# How use keyboard arrow keys to move a div 100px left/right respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id of `bottom_arrow` and I want to use my keyboard arrows left/right to move the div left and right 100px. How can I do this?

Comment: in my own search I have found this http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/htmlcss/animate-a-random-bouncing-ball-with-the-canvas-tag/

Comment: Incidentally, just found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104158/jquery-keypress-left-right-navigation

Comment: Nice example, though HTML5 `<canvas>` is used there, which is not supported in IE until IE9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule keypress events go to an input or some control that has focus, if you need them generally on a page, which is a sometimes a little frowned upon due to removing standard behavior, then bind the keydown event to the whole document.

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.keycode) {
        case 37: // left arrow key
           $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '-=100' });
           break;
        case 39: // right arrow key
           $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '+=100' });
           break;
    }
});
```

I have used `keydown`, rather than `keypress` as a user would expect it to trigger whilst pressing the key.

Comment: @Sam: Quite alright, bear in mind you will probably need to `position` the `<div>` in a way in which altering the `left` position will have the desired effect.

Comment: How should I style the div so I can move it with up and down arrows?

Comment: @Sam: Up/Down are keycodes 38/40, use as with the above, but use the `top` css style.  Make sure the element has `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` if necessary.

Comment: yeah, I meant to say left/right. I've tried the different positions but it hasn't done to much.

Comment: @Sam: It is sometimes difficult to see what the issue is with these problems without seeing the HTML/CSS in question.  Have you used the position attribute for the items you wish to move about?  Post some code on your question and I'll have a look later.

Comment: It didn't work for me because until I changed 'event.keycode' to 'event.keyCode'

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.keycode) {
        case 37: // left arrow key
           $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '-=100' });
           break;
        case 39: // right arrow key
           $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '+=100' });
           break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Jquery documentation, use event.which instead.

```
$('body').keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 37: // left arrow key
            $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '-=100' });
            break;
            case 39: // right arrow key
            $('#bottom_arrow').animate({ 'left': '+=100' });
            break;
    }
});
```