# How can one adjust this jquery keyboard navigation to allow other tags and keyboard functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on creating a simple site with images running vertically down the page. I would like to be able to smooth scroll between images via the keyboard arrow keys. Through the help of this forum, I have received the following suggestion (which does, indeed, work).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aVvQF/5/

Question: [How can one smooth scroll up and down between objects on a page with arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675738/how-can-one-smooth-scroll-up-and-down-between-objects-on-a-page-with-arrow-keys)

However, I need a bit of additional functionality. This setup prevents the default action of all keyboard function. I would only like the default action changed for the left and right arrow keys. I decided to use left and right, instead of up and down, so that the standard up and down arrow navigation and page up and page down will not be affected. How can the code change to allow the expected use of all keys except the left and right arrows?

Also, this setup only seems to work if there are no other tags between the 'img' tags. However, I need to be able to place links, text and line breaks between or around the images. How can the code be adjusted to allow for this? Or, alternatively, would it work better to put the image and the requisite text and links each in 'div' classes running down the page (right now it is all in one 'div') and then have the keyboard navigation go between 'div's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like below for allowing all other keys except left and right arrow keys at the beginning of your function ->

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

//return if it is not left/right arrow key
if (keyCode != 39 && keyCode != 37) {
    return;
}
```

I modified your html and script a bit to make it work. See my approach [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aVvQF/21/)

The next() and next([selector]) works differently. The former next simply gets the next sibling, where else the later tries to get the matching list first ($('.active') in your case and picks the next matching element from there (which is 0).

For example,

```
 <p class="selected active">Hello Again</p>
 <span class="log" >Test</span>
 <p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
 <div><span>And Again</span></div>
```

And this `$("p.selected.active").next('p.selected')` may look like it is going to fetch the next p.selected, but it doesn't. Looks to me like jQuery iterates through `$("p.selected.active")` to find matching 'p.selected' which is going to return empty.

I used .next() and added a where clause to find next img tag in the siblings,

```
 $targetElement = $('.active').next();

 while ($targetElement.length != 0 && $targetElement.hasClass('img') == false) {
       $targetElement = $targetElement.next();
 }
```

I hope it helps

**Edit:**

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aVvQF/23/).

1. Add isAnimating flag to avoid spamming of keydown.
2. Modified css `.active img{ border: 2px dotted red; }`.
3. Changed the html a bit.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Seems to work just as I was hoping.

Comment: Another question... it seems that if the 'img' is within an 'a' tag, that the keyboard smooth scrolling becomes inactive. Is there any way around this (so that the images to which the smooth scrolling is moving can serve as links)? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you put that in jsFiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: See my Edit for changes here is the jsFiddle-> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/aVvQF/23/ . I wondering why you would want to wrap it with 'a' tag? You can use some other container and implement onclick event and as for css you can use cursor: pointer to give link effect.

Comment: Great, thank you. This does allow it to work with 'a' tags. If I run the JSLint checker, it gives a couple suggestions. I added the '='s for which it was asking, but it still gives me this error: Problem at line 11 character 22: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
 if (isAnimating) return; Any idea how to fix this? I am not real experienced with javascript, and the few things I tried disrupted the functionality of the script. Thanks.

Comment: In response to your comment about 'a' vs 'onclick', the main reason I want to use the 'a' is just that it is what I am more familiar with -- I have minimal javascript experience.

Comment: Please change if (isAnimating) return; as if (isAnimating) { return false; } and try.

Comment: Yes, it (JSLint) likes that. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate you helping me figure this out. I have been implementing it and testing it in the actual page on which I want to use it also (not yet online), and it all seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

> How can the code change to allow the expected use of all keys except the left and right arrows?

Only call `e.preventDefault();` when you have a match of left/right keys

> How can the code be adjusted to allow for this?

You should be able to surround each set of data with a container div and change the code to look for the divs instead of the images.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KnKC9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/aVvQF/11/ However, the other keyboard functions still do not complete their function. They try to, it seems, but are prevented. Did I not change the 'e.preventDefault();' properly?

Comment: I added an example with the basic idea. Not sure if it is perfect, but should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Nice to see it also done with 'li'. However, the other keyboard functions still do not seem to work while in the midst of the left-right navigation. For example, if one has navigated right for a few arrow key presses, and then tries to press the up or down arrow keys to move just a bit, it tries to move and then jumps back to the currently active 'div' or 'li'. Is there some way to allow the use of the other keys for the default function?