# Smooth scroll div horizontally by a pixel amount, no scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

I've got 10 floating DIVs in a container DIV that I want to be able to scroll through using a button.

I'd like to use left/right buttons to make the container DIV scroll 300px horizontally to display the next floating DIV.

I'd like the width of the container to appear as 100% of the window, and I'd also like there to be no horizontal scroll-bar on the bottom. If it could scroll sideways that'd be great but it's not a must have.

Here's what I've got:
http://jsfiddle.net/696je/

I'm just looking for a function and the way to activate the function for left/right buttons.

I've tried Google for hours, I've tried Flesler's ScrollTo but I haven't had any luck, it might be something do to with the way I've got the width set up, anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand that you've said you've tried to google for hours, and you've tried a ScrollTo plugin... but you haven't shown us WHAT you have tried, so therefore it could be suggested that you haven't tried anything... I suggest posting the code you have tried, and then we can try and fix it for you, hopefully helping you to understand it a bit better in the process.

Comment: tldr: Please post the code you HAVE tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do with mix of `CSS` (`display:inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap`) and `jQuery` (`scrollLeft`)

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya5pr/) implementation with minimum possible wrappers.

Comment: This is great, there's just one quirk: the content (text) inside the .item divs goes beyond the borders, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Never mind, I added other white-space tag. One other thing: can I activate the function with an <a> tag?

Comment: yeah u can activate the function on <a> tag but remember to prevent event using preventDefault otherwise your page might reload

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused by your code you posted in the jsFiddle. You said you wanted no horizontal scroll bars, yet your stuff was set up that way. I went with the horizontal scroll bar since that is what you were going with in your code.

I made a working function here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWgtm/). To get it to work in the frame you need to put focus in the "Result" window (just click anywhere), then use your left and right arrows.

I must give the javascript for keypress credit from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4104439/892792)