# Go to link when pressing keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript

I have 2 links: `<a href='leftLink.php'><< Prev</a>` and `<a href='rightLink.php'>Next >></a>`.

Can it be possible to go to `leftLink when pressing left arrow from keyboard`, and to `rightLink.php when pressing right arrow from keyboard`? Any advice would be very welcome

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Worth considering that this approach might hijack arrow keys for screen readers that use them to navigate through various page elements: https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup a keyboard event listener (`keydown` or `keyup`) on the document.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',(event)=>{});
```

Check the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property (modern browsers) or [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) (deprecated, older browsers) on the `event` object for the appropriate value corresponding to the left and right arrows.

```
switch(event.key){
    case 'ArrowLeft':
    break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
    break;
}
```

Then use the `click()` method of the respective link to trigger the navigation.

```
document.getElementById("prevLink").click();
```

```js
let prevLink = document.getElementById("prevLink");
let nextLink = document.getElementById("nextLink");
document.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      console.log('Left arrow');
      prevLink.click();
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      console.log('Right arrow');
      nextLink.click();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<a id="prevLink" href='#prevUrl'><< Prev</a>

<a id="nextLink" href='#nextUrl'>Next >></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to detect keypress..

```
function checkKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    if (true) {
        alert(event.keyCode)
    }
}
```

from here determine the key pressed and use document.location to redirect the browser.

keycodes are:

```
left = 37
up = 38
right = 39
down = 40
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    //your code
    window.location.href = "leftLink.php";
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    //your code
    window.location.href = "rightLink.php";
  }
});
```

## [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104158/jquery-keypress-left-right-navigation)

Comment: jQuery is not tagged, you should show a pure javascript solution, and then suggest jQuery if needed. While jQuery is a good library, he might not be using it, and adding it just for this would just add overhead to do a simple task

Comment: OP did't mention he want javascript solution. @PatrickEvans +1 for your ans this one is also good.

Comment: OP has it tagged javascript, I am just saying since it is not tagged with jQuery you cannot assume he knows what jQuery is or know if he is even using it.